Calculate confidence interval in multiple dimensions
I would like to calculate the confidence interval of a multidimensional probability vector X ($p$ dimensions, r realizations). I feel like I got pretty far already but somehow the last step seems to be missing.
Here it is shown, that the confidence interval should be an ellipsoid in the $p$ dimensional space. The principle axes can be determined by principle component analysis of the covariance matrix $C=X^T\cdot X/\sqrt{(p-1)}$:
$$
C=V\cdot L \cdot V^T
$$
now the columns of $V$ (Eigenvectors) should be the directions of the principle axes of the ellipsoid and the square roots of the diagonal elements of $L$ should be their lengths. $A=V\cdot \sqrt{L}$ are called the loadings. (From here I know how I have to scale the ellipsoid to cover a certain percentage of realizations. Also I know how to apply dimensionality reduction.) Now all I need to do is to find the points where the ellipsoid hits the coordinate axes. Or in other words, which principle component contributes to which entry of my vector to which extend. Can I simply sum up the rows of the loadings $A$? I cannot make sense of the fact, that I end up with positive and negative values and the results do not seem to fit. Where am I going wrong?
I hope I was able to state my problem and would really appreciate your help.
Edit: I added a 2D sketch to show what I need for $p$ dimenstions. To recieve the confidents bounds, I need to find the blue rectangle I inserted above. It represents the smallest possible cuboid surrounding the tilted ellipsoid. Any ideas how to retrieve this from the Eigenvalue-Decomposition (or any other way)?


Re "ll I need to do is to find the points where the ellipsoid hits the coordinate axes:" that surprises me, because it's incomplete information and usually is not related to any meaningful statistical interpretation.  Are you sure this is what you want to ask?

Well, the idea is to calculate how much each PCA (principal axis) contributes to each entry of X, i.e. how far does the ellipsoid range in each direction of the coordinate system. Can't that be done by determining the points where the ellipsoid touches with the axes of the coordinate system?

No, it cannot.  Look at it in 2D: draw a pair of points $\pm x$ on the horizontal axis and a pair $\pm y$ on the vertical axis.  You should be able to find a lot of ellipses that cross the axes at precisely those four points ("a lot" = a one-parameter family).

Okay, that makes sense. So what I have to do is to back-project the dimensionality-reduced distribuition into the original coordinate system by doing
$$ C_{red}=V_{red}L_{red}V_{red}^T$$
and read the variances of the entries of $X$ from the diagonal elements of $C_{red}$, right?

I'm not completely clear about your notation, but it looks right.  This "back-projection" amounts to ignoring the variables you are not concerned about.  For example, the usual way to construct CIs for individual variables uses the diagonal elements of the variance-covariance matrix of their estimates.  No additional calculations are needed.

I got more clarity about what I need now: see edit.

It's a good diagram.  But it doesn't answer your question: the bounding box of that ellipsoid is a poor confidence region, because it covers more than you intended.  It illustrates the fact that the Cartesian product of two confidence intervals almost always has far greater confidence than the levels of the individual intervals.

The blue rectangle has a much larger probabability, do you really want that as confidence interval? Check the image at the end of this answer. There you see that, if you do want to use a rectangle, then the rectangle based on the straightforward standard error computations is smaller than the approach that you suggest.

I think maybe you're looking for something like this: stats.stackexchange.com/a/373988/77222

The ellipse relates to points where the term in the density distribution $x^T \Sigma^{-1} x < L$ has zero change in all directions except one coordinate.
This makes us solve the following for the 1st coordinate (and you can do similar for the others)
$$ \nabla \left(x'^T\Sigma^{-1} x'\right) =  \left( {\Sigma^{-1}}^{T}+  \Sigma^{-1}\right) x' = 2   \Sigma^{-1} x'  = \begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $x'$ is on a line parameterised by $z_1$
$$x' = z_1 \Sigma/2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
 \end{bmatrix}$$
then for $z_1$ you compute $x' \Sigma^{-1} x' = L$ which is solving the 2nd order polynomial
$$  z_1^2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix} \Sigma/4 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 
 \end{bmatrix} = \Sigma_{11}/4z_1^2= L$$
and filling in $z_1 = 2 \sqrt{L/\Sigma_{11}}$ to find the first coordinate of $x'$ you get $\sqrt{\Sigma_{11}L}$.
Code demonstration

Sigma = matrix(c(2,1,
                 1,3), 2)

### coordinates of the bounding rectangle 
z1 = sqrt(Sigma[1,1])
z2 = sqrt(Sigma[2,2])


### empty canvas
m = max(z1,z2)
plot(100,100, 
     xlab = expression(x[1]),
     ylab = expression(x[2]),
     xlim = c(-m,m),
     ylim = c(-m,m),
)

### draw points with color for cases where
### x^t Sigma^-1 x is above 1
for (i in 1:10000) {
  x1 = runif(1,-z1,z1)
  x2 = runif(1,-z2,z2)
  p = c(x1,x2) %*%  solve(Sigma) %*% 
  c(x1,x2)
  points(x1,x2, col = 1 + (p>1), pch = 20)
}

